# Prove that $b_{\perp}^{T}b_{\parallel}=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{mxn}$ then the unique expansion of every $b \in \mathbb{R^{m}}$ is $b =b_{\perp}+b_{\parallel} $.  Prove that $b_{\perp}^{T}b_{\parallel}$.

Comment: Saying that they are orthogonal does not help.  Need to be more rigorous and talk about $b_{\parallel} \in$ Range($A$) and $b_{\perp} \in$ Null($A^{T}$) and go from there.

Comment: Should it be $\vec{b}\in \mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: Yes thank you..been edited

Comment: Express $b_{\parallel}$ as a linear combination of the columns of $A$ and then bring $b_{\perp}^T$ into the summation. Is this homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Express $b_{\parallel}$ as a linear combination of the columns of $A$ and then bring $b_{\perp}^T$ into the summation.

Remember that $A^Tb_{\perp}=\mathbf{0}$. So take the transpose. What does this tell you about $b_{\perp}^T a_i$, if $a_i$ is a column of $A$?

Comment: Since $b_{\parallel} \in$ Range($A$), it can be expressed as a linear combination of the columns of $A$.  Thus,

Comment: Since $b_{\parallel} \in$ Range($A$), it can be expressed as a linear combination of the columns of $A$.  Thus,      $b_{\parallel}=\sum c_{i}a_{i}$ where $a_{i}$ are the columns of $A$ for $i=1,...,n$.  Taking the inner product of both sides yields: $(b_{\perp}^{T},b_{\parallel})= \sum (b_{\perp}^{T},c_{i}a_{i})$.  Since as you stated above, that $A^{T}b_{\perp}=Ab_{\perp}^{T}=0$, $b_{\perp}$ is perpendicular to all the columns of $A$. Thus, $(b_{\perp}^{T},b_{\parallel})=0$.

Comment: Thank you!!  My only question now is how would I go about that if $Ab_{\perp}^{T}=0$, how does that imply that $b_{\perp}^{T}a_{i}=0$ for all $a_{i}$?

Comment: @Tim Take the transpose, you get $b_{\perp}^TA=0$. Look at each value of the row vector.